# Create DOM Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="comments"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const darkModeMeidaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

    function updateForDarkModeChange() {
        if (darkModeMeidaQuery.matches) {
            var colorScheme = 'dark'
        } else {
            var colorScheme = 'light'
        }
        $('.comments').append('<script src="https://utteranc.es/client.js" repo="user/repo-name" issue-term="pathname" theme="github-'+colorScheme+'" crossorigin="anonymous" async><\/script>');
    }

    darkModeMeidaQuery.addListener(updateForDarkModeChange);
    updateForDarkModeChange();
</script>
```

I'm trying to load [utterances](https://github.com/utterance/utterances) to match browser theme with the above script.
However, the object is created normally, but it throws: `Uncaught Error: "issue-term" or "issue-number" must be specified.`
I tried escaping characters, but it didn't works.
Is there any part that I wrote wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice job! Most new users do not include a minimally reproducible example, which you've done!

When in doubt, always [consult the issue tracker](https://github.com/utterance/utterances/issues/82#issuecomment-431620350). You didn't do anything wrong, but jQuery is wiping out your properties.

Follow the instructions from the issue comment:

```html
<div id="comments"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const darkModeMeidaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    const comments = document.getElementById('comments');
 
    function updateForDarkModeChange() {
        if (darkModeMeidaQuery.matches) {
            var colorScheme = 'dark'
        } else {
            var colorScheme = 'light'
        }
 
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://utteranc.es/client.js';
        script.setAttribute('repo', 'ergo9ine/sfdb_tracker');
        script.setAttribute('issue-term', 1);
        script.setAttribute('theme', 'github-dark');
        script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        comments.appendChild(script)
    }

    darkModeMeidaQuery.addListener(updateForDarkModeChange);
    updateForDarkModeChange();
</script>
```